# SQL Broker Activation Proc Logging Excessively

Tags: sql-server

I decided to add logging to a SQL Broker Queue's Activation stored procedure - the goal is to log errors.  Upon testing, the log-table is continuously filling with errors.

**BEFORE ADDING LOGGING:**

- Everything works great
- No system or event logs show an issue
- Server performance shows barely a 'blip'

**AFTER ADDING LOGGING:**
The server performance still shows barely a 'blip', but...

- The log-table is continuously filling with THE FOLLOWING error

> The service queue "OutboundEventRequestQueue" is currently disabled.

- The logging doesn't stop until I run the following command

  ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabaseName] SET NEW_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

**THE STORED PROCEDURE:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_OutboundEventRequestQueueActivation]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @MessageBody XML; 
    DECLARE @MessageTypeName SYSNAME;

    ---------------
    -- READS ALL THE MESSAGES IN THE QUEUE
    ---------------
    WHILE (1=1)
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            ---------------
            -- KEEPS READING While In 'Notified' State
            ---------------
            WAITFOR
            (
                RECEIVE TOP (1)
                    @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
                    @MessageBody = CAST(message_body AS XML),
                    @MessageTypeName = message_type_name
                FROM [dbo].[OutboundEventRequestQueue]
            ), TIMEOUT 5000;

            IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                BREAK;
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE REPLY MESSAGE: OutboundEventRequest
            ---------------
            IF @MessageTypeName = N'OutboundEventRequestMessageType'
            BEGIN 

                -- DEBUG ONLY: Use to force an error
                --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

                --------------
                --  INSERT AUDIT
                --------------
                DECLARE @AuditedEvent XML;
                EXEC [event].[usp_tOutbound_Audit_UPSERT] @MessageBody, @AuditedEvent = @AuditedEvent OUTPUT

                ---------------
                -- DO WORK
                ---------------

                -- Publish XML Message (payload) to Outbound Event Aggregator (using SQL CLR)
                DECLARE @Payload NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @AuditedEvent))
                EXEC dbo.usp_OutboundEventMessage_PUBLISH @outboundEvent = @Payload

                -- SEND REPLY
                DECLARE @ReplyMessageBody XML = @MessageBody;
                SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle MESSAGE TYPE [OutboundEventResponseMessageType] (@ReplyMessageBody);
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE ERRORS: for EndDialog MessageTypes
            ---------------
            ELSE IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'
            BEGIN

                -- CLOSE CONVERSATION
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE ERRORS: for Error MessageTypes
            ---------------
            ELSE IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
            BEGIN

                -- CLOSE CONVERSATION
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
            END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

            DECLARE @Error_Number INT = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER())
            DECLARE @Error_Message VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
            DECLARE @Error_Severity INT = (SELECT ERROR_SEVERITY())
            DECLARE @Error_State INT = (SELECT ERROR_STATE())
            DECLARE @Error_Procedure VARCHAR(400) = (SELECT ERROR_PROCEDURE())
            DECLARE @Error_Line INT = (SELECT ERROR_LINE())

            -- HERE: The log-table is continuously FILLING-UP
            EXEC [event].[usp_Exceptions_TRYINSERT]
                @Error_Number,
                @Error_Message,
                @Error_Severity,
                @Error_State,
                @Error_Procedure,
                @Error_Line
        END CATCH
    END
END
```

**THE QUEUE:**

```
ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[OutboundEventRequestQueue] WITH STATUS = OFF , RETENTION = OFF , ACTIVATION (  STATUS = ON , PROCEDURE_NAME = [dbo].[usp_OutboundEventRequestQueueActivation] , MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 10 , EXECUTE AS OWNER  ), POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING (STATUS = ON)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I now feel stupid.  I am surprised no one caught this...heck I'm surprised I didn't.

**THE PROBLEM CODE:**

> WHILE (1=1)

**THE CORRECTED STORED PROCEDURE:**
This will catch the error correctly

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_OutboundEventRequestQueueActivation]
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ConversationHandle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    DECLARE @MessageBody XML; 
    DECLARE @MessageTypeName SYSNAME;

    DECLARE @RunningState TINYINT = 1;

    ---------------
    -- READS ALL THE MESSAGES IN THE QUEUE
    --------------
    WHILE (@RunningState = 1)
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

            ---------------
            -- KEEPS READING While In 'Notified' State
            ---------------
            WAITFOR
            (
                RECEIVE TOP (1)
                    @ConversationHandle = conversation_handle,
                    @MessageBody = CAST(message_body AS XML),
                    @MessageTypeName = message_type_name
                FROM [dbo].[OutboundEventRequestQueue]
            ), TIMEOUT 5000;

            IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
                BREAK;
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE REPLY MESSAGE: OutboundEventRequest
            ---------------
            IF @MessageTypeName = N'OutboundEventRequestMessageType'
            BEGIN 

                -- DEBUG ONLY: Use to force an error
                --WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'

                --------------
                --  INSERT AUDIT
                --------------
                DECLARE @AuditedEvent XML;
                EXEC [event].[usp_tOutbound_Audit_UPSERT] @MessageBody, @AuditedEvent = @AuditedEvent OUTPUT

                ---------------
                -- DO WORK
                ---------------

                -- Publish XML Message (payload) to Outbound Event Aggregator (using SQL CLR)
                DECLARE @Payload NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @AuditedEvent))
                EXEC dbo.usp_OutboundEventMessage_PUBLISH @outboundEvent = @Payload

                -- SEND REPLY
                DECLARE @ReplyMessageBody XML = @MessageBody;
                SEND ON CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle MESSAGE TYPE [OutboundEventResponseMessageType] (@ReplyMessageBody);
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE ERRORS: for EndDialog MessageTypes
            ---------------
            ELSE IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog'
            BEGIN

                -- CLOSE CONVERSATION
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
            END

            ---------------
            -- HANDLE ERRORS: for Error MessageTypes
            ---------------
            ELSE IF @MessageTypeName = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
            BEGIN

                -- CLOSE CONVERSATION
                END CONVERSATION @ConversationHandle;
            END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH

            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

            SET @RunningState = 0;

            DECLARE @Error_Number INT = (SELECT ERROR_NUMBER())
            DECLARE @Error_Message VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE())
            DECLARE @Error_Severity INT = (SELECT ERROR_SEVERITY())
            DECLARE @Error_State INT = (SELECT ERROR_STATE())
            DECLARE @Error_Procedure VARCHAR(400) = (SELECT ERROR_PROCEDURE())
            DECLARE @Error_Line INT = (SELECT ERROR_LINE())

            EXEC [event].[usp_Exceptions_TRYINSERT]
                @Error_Number,
                @Error_Message,
                @Error_Severity,
                @Error_State,
                @Error_Procedure,
                @Error_Line
        END CATCH
    END
END
```